# (1170, u"BLOB/TEXT column 'user_id' used in key specification without a key length")

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am using a MySQL db in my flask app. I am using SQLAlchemy with pymysql too. The app is deployed on a web server(linux based - specifically Ubuntu). I am trying to apply migrations using flask-migrate but I keep on getting the error

(1170, u"BLOB/TEXT column 'user_id' used in key specification without a key length")

My primary keys look like this:

```
id = db.Column(db.String(32),default=lambda: str(uuid4().hex), primary_key=True)
```

The specific table where this error arises is an association table: The code is

```
user_association_table = db.Table('association', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('user_id', db.String(32), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('article_id', db.String(32), db.ForeignKey('article.id'))
)
```

I have seen similar questions but they address how to fix it using MySQL directly. Since I have minimal control of how mysql is generated, how can I bypass this error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the original MySQL db that I was trying to apply migrations to was not fully up to date with the size of the primary key `--> db.String(32)` Deleting and recreating the database made migrations work just fine. 
If the database has data then it would be more painful to recreate the database without losing data.